# lodash - Sort based on values of different keys?

Tags: lodash

I have an array of objects, with their quantities (`fruit_quantity`/`vegetable_quantity`):

I am trying to sort by those quantities, so it shows the order from highest to lowest with lodash.

```
var items = [
    {'type': 'fruit', 'name': 'apple', 'fruit_quantity': 20},
    {'type': 'fruit', 'name': 'banana','fruit_quantity': 10},
    {'type': 'vegetable', 'name': 'brocolli','vegetable_quantity': 15},
    {'type': 'fruit', 'name': 'cantaloupe','fruit_quantity': 5}
];

var sortedItems = _.sortBy(items, ['fruit_quantity' || 'vegetable_quantity']).reverse();
```

I know that if they were the same key, like `quantity`, then it will be done like this:

```
var sortedItems = _.sortBy(items, 'quantity').reverse();
```

But unfortunately I have to use different keys, but still sort with their respective quantity.

Here is a fiddle with my attempt:
https://jsfiddle.net/zg6js8af/1/

How can I sort the items by their highest to lowest quantities?

This is what the final sort order should look like:

```
{'type': 'fruit', 'name': 'apple', 'fruit_quantity': 20},
{'type': 'vegetable', 'name': 'brocolli','vegetable_quantity': 15},
{'type': 'fruit', 'name': 'banana','fruit_quantity': 10},
{'type': 'fruit', 'name': 'cantaloupe','fruit_quantity': 5}
```

Comment: So, you want to sort them by `vegetable_quantity` and secondary to `fruit_quantity` both `descending`? Or you just want to sort them by general quantity?

Comment: I added what it should look like, basically highest to lowest quantity, where that is fruit or vegetable quantity, should be treated as the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to detect which property exists, and then return it. An example using `Array#sort`:

```js
var items = [
    {'type': 'fruit', 'name': 'apple', 'fruit_quantity': 20},
    {'type': 'fruit', 'name': 'banana','fruit_quantity': 10},
    {'type': 'vegetable', 'name': 'brocolli','vegetable_quantity': 15},
    {'type': 'fruit', 'name': 'cantaloupe','fruit_quantity': 5}
];

function getQuantity(item) {
  return item.fruit_quantity || item.vegetable_quantity || 0;
}

items.sort(function(a, b) {
  return getQuantity(a) - getQuantity(b);
});

console.log(items);
```

You can do the same with `_.sortBy()`:

```js
var items = [
    {'type': 'fruit', 'name': 'apple', 'fruit_quantity': 20},
    {'type': 'fruit', 'name': 'banana','fruit_quantity': 10},
    {'type': 'vegetable', 'name': 'brocolli','vegetable_quantity': 15},
    {'type': 'fruit', 'name': 'cantaloupe','fruit_quantity': 5}
];

function getQuantity(item) {
  return item.fruit_quantity || item.vegetable_quantity || 0;
}

var result = _.sortBy(items, getQuantity);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you :)

Comment: Just wondering why there is a `0`  return if those quantities don't exist. Also, in my fiddle it works with your `_.sortBy()` but hitting Run code snippet above, isn't sorting correctly for some reason?

Comment: The 0 is for `fruit_quantity` with the value of 0. In which case `vegetable_quantity` will be undefined, so we still want to return 0. I see the sort problem. Checking...

Comment: Fixed. I've forgot that `_.sortBy()` doesn't mutate the original array, but produces a new sorted one.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for explaining and everything works as expected. Thank you Ori :)

Comment: Welcome @Wonka :)